# Not able to access mailman via web interface

Tags: debian, mailman

I am trying to install `mailman` on my local machine. I am using debian 8. I installed mailman simply using `apt-get install mailman`. Then i copied `mailman.conf` file to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mailman.conf`.

Now when i am trying to open this link in my browser `localhost/mailman/listinfo` then instead of opening the page it is downloading that script which should not be happening.

This is mailman.conf file.

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/mailman/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/
# And the public archives:
Alias /pipermail/ /var/lib/mailman/archives/public/
# Logos:
Alias /images/mailman/ /usr/share/images/mailman/

# Use this if you don't want the "cgi-bin" component in your URL:
# In case you want to access mailman through a shorter URL you should enable
# this:
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/
# In this case you need to set the DEFAULT_URL_PATTERN in
# /etc/mailman/mm_cfg.py to http://%s/mailman/ for the cookie
# authentication code to work.  Note that you need to change the base
# URL for all the already-created lists as well.

<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/>
  AllowOverride None
  Options ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
#     Order allow,deny
#    Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/lib/mailman/archives/public/>
  Options FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride None
#    Order allow,deny
#    Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/images/mailman/>
  AllowOverride None
#    Order allow,deny
#    Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is what i am getting now on doing `tail -f *.log` in `/var/log/apache2`. 
In my browser i put this `localhost/cgi-bin/mailman/confirm`

```
::1 - - [01/Jun/2015:14:43:36 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/mailman/confirm HTTP/1.1" 200 10463 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.6.0"
```

I am confused as what to do.

Comment: This indicates that the script handler is not active. Check the apache config if it matches your setup. Also try https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-configure-mailman-with-postfix-on-debian-squeeze

Comment: @EliDevender what is apache configbifbit ? Please care to explain.

Comment: "Config if it" sorry...

Comment: @EliDevender I have edited my question with mailman.conf file. I am not able to find anything out of ordinary in it.

Comment: Seems to be ok. Any error in your apache log?

Comment: @EliDevender I have edited my question with apache logs. They seems ok giving 200.

Answer (score 1):

In my own fresh Apache2 installation on Debian 8, I found to my surprise that the CGI Apache module was not enabled by default. This may the case in your situation as well.

Try:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

...and see if that makes things better. (It did for me.)

Answer (score 0):

In Debian the configuration in `sites-available` is not automatically applied. I believe you'll need to do something like

```
sudo a2ensite mailmain
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

and see if that allows the CGI to be properly interpreted.